# Linux command output as input at particular location of another command.?

Tags: linux, docker

i am using docker command on Linux operating system

```
docker ps | awk '{print $NF;}' | docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'
```

in this command need container name at last, to show their Internal IP Address.

is it possible to put container name at last of this command.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix

```
docker ps -a |awk 'NR>1{print $NF}'|xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'
```

another way

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -a -q)
```